# Does it exist a web applet without plugin?

Tags: web-applications, plugins, applet

Simple question: does it exist a web-applet that doesn't require any plugin? I would like to develop a web application but I don't want to ask to the user to install Flash, Java or Silverlight, for example...

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery-ui components offer applet-like funcionality, without requiring any plugin.

Comment: Thank you. Is it imaginable to develop a webmail with jquery? What about security?

Comment: Actually most modern Web applications are based on frameworks that are based on jquery (Take a look at Angular and Backbone)

Comment: Okay! I take your answer as a yes. Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. And don't forget to check the answer if you liked it.

Comment: Just subsidiary question: is it possible to send IMAP requests with Angular? So without using technologies as Ajax to run the IMAP query on server side?

Comment: I don't think so. Probably you'll have to build a server component that  gets that job done.

Comment: Maybe some IMAP server offers a REST API you can invoke from angular.